# C printf difference between 0 flag & width attribute and precision flag

Tags: c, printf, libc

I'm currently learning the `printf` function of libc and I don't understand, what is the difference between:

```
printf("Test : %010d", 10);
```

using the `0` flag and `10` as width specifier

and

```
printf("Test : %.10d", 10);
```

using `10` as precision specifier

That produce the same output: `Test : 0000000010`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We'll start with [the docs for printf()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) and I'll highlight their relevant bits.

First 0 padding.

> `0' (zero)
>
> Zero padding.  ***For all conversions except n, the converted value is padded on the left with zeros rather than blanks.***  If a precision is given with a numeric conversion (d, i, o, u, i, x, and X), the 0 flag is ignored.

And then precision.

> An optional precision, in the form of a period . followed by an optional digit string.  If the digit string is omitted, the precision is taken as zero.  ***This gives the minimum number of digits to appear for d, i, o, u, x, and X conversions***, the number of digits to appear after the decimal-point for a, A, e, E, f, and F conversions, the maximum number of significant digits for g and G conversions, or the maximum number of characters to be printed from a string for s conversions.

`%010d` says to zero-pad to a minimum width of 10 digits. No problem there.

`%.10d"`, because you're using `%d`, says the minimum number of digits to appear is 10. So the same thing as zero padding. `%.10f` would behave more like you expected.

I would recommend you use `%010d` to zero pad. The `%.10d` form is a surprising feature that might confuse readers. I didn't know about it and I'm surprised it isn't simply ignored.

Comment: You seem to be preferring `%010d` based on the mere fact that you find `%.10d` "surprising". There's nothing surprising in it.

Comment: @AnT To put it in UX terms, it overloads a control with multiple meanings, and breaks its affordance. The affordance of `%.10f`, because it looks so much like a floating point number, says "this affects how many digits come after the decimal". OTOH `%010d`'s affordances line up with its behavior. When a control has different meanings in different contexts it makes it harder to remember what all those behaviors are and when they apply. When one of those meanings dominates use and lines up with the affordances, readers might not even know the other behaviors exist.

Comment: Well, that is the reality of `printf`. That precision part has its own specific semantics with strings as well, and knowing that semantics is an absolute must for any user of `printf`. That alone should be sufficient to break that completely unjustified illusion that precision in `printf` format is somehow tied to floating-point output. If "readers don't even know the other behaviors exist", it means that this is their lucky day and they finally get to learn something new (especially considering that this is critical knowledge).

Comment: @AnT When writing maintainable code, especially in languages like C that are littered with pitfalls and bad design choices, we choose which features we use. By choosing the ones that reduce complexity and assumptions of knowledge on the reader, we avoid errors based on misunderstandings, slips, and our inevitable incomplete knowledge. In short, it's useful to know what `%.010d` does in case you encounter it, but use `%010d` yourself. This is the Robustness Principle: "*Be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept*".

Comment: Yes, but this feature of `printf` does not even begin to fall into that category. This is basic kindergarten-level knowledge, mastery of which is an undisputable requirement for anyone even attempting to touch C compiler professionally. Things like that are instantly recognizable to a C programmer at subconscious level. They require no mental effort to understand. This feature of `printf` is there specifically to *reduce complexity*. Not knowing it and not being able to use it will only lead to reinvention of the wheel, thus unnecessarily *increasing* complexity of the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127934/discussion-between-schwern-and-ant).

Answer (score 6):

Both formats produce the same output for positive numbers, but the output differs for negative numbers greater than `-1000000000`:

`printf("Test : %010d", -10);` produces `-000000010`

whereas

`printf("Test : %.10d", -10);` produces `-0000000010`

Format `%010d` pads the output with leading zeroes upto a *width* of 10 characters.

Format `%.10d` pads the converted number with leading zeroes upto 10 *digits*.

The second form is useful if you want to produce no output for value `0` but otherwise produce the normal conversion like `%d`:

```
printf("%.0d", 0);  // no output
printf("%.0d", 10);  // outputs 10
```

Also note that the initial `0` in the first form is a flag: it can be combined with other flags in any order as in `%0+10d` which produces `+000000010` and it can be used with an indirect width as in `printf("%0*d", 10, 10);` which produces `0000000010`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference besides maybe a purely conceptual one.

In the first case you are just filling the blank area with completely independent padding `0` characters. In the second case these zeros are leading zeros created when converting your argument value. (This is admittedly very contrived.)

In any case these zeros look, smell and quack the same.

---

However, in general case there's one obscure specific situation when precision behaves differently from padded field-width: when you are asking for zero field width and print zero value. When zero *precision* is used, zero values are simply not printed at all. When zero *field-width* is used, zero values will appear as usual

```
printf("%00d\n", 0); // prints '0'
printf("%.0d\n", 0); // prints nothing
```

Obviously this is also a very contrived situation, since no padding occurs in this case.

Comment: The number of leading zeroes also differs for some of the negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In your second case *you probably expected* 10.0000000000 - but `%d` is only for **integers**. The specification says:

> For integer specifiers (d, i, o, u, x, X): precision specifies the minimum number of digits to be written.

(Precision is the part started with `.` , so in your case `10` .)

So, with `%.10d` you specified at least `10` digits to express the two-digit number, so it is completed with the 8 leading zeroes.

It means that both `%010d` and `%.10d` will produce the same result.

Comment: Given the vocabulary used by the OP, I doubt he would make this confusion.